# Linq to Sql - Loading Child Entities Without Using DataLoadOptions?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to load child entities in a ***single*** query without using DataLoadOptions?

I am using one data context per request in an asp.net web application and trying to get around the linq to sql limitation of not being able to change dataloadoptions once a query has been executed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind the link to the data context, as you say you don't, you could write a stored procedure that returns multiple results that map to your objects. [Read more about it here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/05/linq-to-sql-stored-procedures-with-multiple-results-imultipleresults.aspx).

Comment: Omer: I know you can return multiple resultsets but can can you return entities with their child entities already populated? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Just select the specific entities you want and return them. You have a sample in the link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following vb.net example which manually populates child entities from an IMultipleResults type:

```
   Public Function GetSubjectsWithBooks() As List(Of Subject)
        Dim results As IMultipleResults = Me.GetSubjectAndBooks
        Dim Subjects = results.GetResult(Of Subject).ToList
        Dim Books = results.GetResult(Of Book).ToList
        For Each s In Subjects
            Dim thisId As Guid = s.ID
            s.FetchedBooks = (From b In Books Where b.SubjectId = thisId).ToList
        Next
        Return Subjects
    End Function
```

This was taken from a sample project written by Jim Wooley (one of the Link in Action authors) which can be found at:http://www.thinqlinq.com/Downloads/LinqToSqlBeyondTheBasics.zip

Omer, is this the technique you were referring to?

Comment: Yes. I don't know who downvoted me, but this is what I talked about and linked to. It's pretty much the best answer you can get.

Answer (score 1):

[Rob Conery's blog](http://blog.wekeroad.com/) has a way to do using a helper class he has, `LazyList<T>`. Also he uses custom objects to avoid the join anonymous type issue.
I've used this successfully to get parent child relationships from sql without DataLoadOptions.

I think he covers it in either Pt2 or Pt3 of his MVC Storefront videos:

[http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-351.aspx](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-352.aspx)

http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-352.aspx

This assumes you have POCO called Category (not linq entity) and a LazyList class:

```
var categories = (from c in _db.Categories
                  select new Category
                  {
                  CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
                  CategoryName = c.CategoryName,
                  ParentCategoryID = c.ParentCategoryID,
                  SubCategories = new LazyList<Category>(
                       from sc in _db.Categories
                       where sc.ParentCategoryID == c.CategoryID
                       select new Category
                       {
                            CategoryID = sc.CategoryID,
                            CategoryName = sc.CategoryName,
                            ParentCategoryID = sc.ParentCategoryID
                        })
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The child entities will be loaded when you first access them, so you can force Linq to Sql to load them by accessing them... :-) But I don't think that is what you were thinking of.

What is your situation? Do you have child entities stored in the same table as the parent entity and want to fetch them all using one query?

Answer (score 0):

What about joins? E.g.:

```
from a in Albums join  o in Users on a.Owner equals o select new {a, o}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your collection is an *EntitySet* then you can load it by the .Load() method:

```
Person p = ctx.Persons.First();
p.Addresses.Load();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Include...

var q = from u in context.Users.Include("address")...

Would cause the address child object to be populated as well.

Comment: Chmad, Include() is not part of LINQ to SQL, it is available in the Entity Framework.